# Сортировка каталога

Tags: ajax, json, сортировка, битрикс

Вот у меня есть html готовая таблица товаров, которую сформировал битриксовый компонент `catalog.section`. Стандартными средствами битрикса не получается сделать, так как цена у нас не стандартная, наценка зависит и от бренда, и от клиента, и от товара.  И эта наценка описана не в битриксовской таблице.

Вопрос, можно ли записать html таблицу в json и как? Чтобы посредством аякс на сервере отсортировать плагинами `Zazza/Kenju`, `jqgrid` ? Как лучше?
Почему именно на сервере, потому что, если выполнять сортировку на клиенте, время сортировки прямо пропорциональна работе процессора клиента. Если у клиента слабый процессор, то сортировка будет выполнятся очень медленно.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно это делать не записью html в JSON, а [подготовкой нового шаблона](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2829) для `catalog.section`.

В шаблоне вы сразу сортируете-пакуете всё это дело в массив, которому потом делаете `json_encode`.

Для вызова компонента создаете отдельный файл, в котом грузите только `/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php`, чтобы не загружать основной шаблон.

Ну, и не забывайте про `UTF-8`, который нужен для JSON'а и `json_encode`

Comment: "В шаблоне вы сразу сортируете-пакуете всё это дело в массив, которому потом делаете json_encode. " уточните, пожалуйста.....
Я понимаю, что надо сортировать яваскриптом , как в моем случае, цену, отсортированные индекс и бренд записать в json? посредством аякс вызвать компонент. Так? что-то мнится, что у вас что-другое имеется ввиду....

Comment: Шаблон php -- т. е. сортировка на стороне сервера. Для того же `jqgrid` это обязательно придется делать, если хочется скорость.

Comment: @AndrewNilolsky, спасибо, но я не понимаю....То есть ,если я хочу отсортировать либо по коду, либо по описанию, либо по фирме- то сортировка идет по всем полям.Если я хочу отсортировать либо по цене либо по сроку поставки либо по нал. - то сортировка идет внутри объединенного блока.
Храню данные в json (ид товара, кол-во потомков, ид потомка, фирма, код, описание, нал., срок поставки, цена).Отправить json на сервер ajax запросом. Возвращаем готовую html таблицу отсортированную. Вопрос как отсортировать на сервере? http://prntscr.com/980y42